# DataTables get source from JSON not well formed because of {} instead of []

Tags: php, json, datatable

i'm trying to refresh a datatables with datas from a json source.
I select a type in a combo, then i submit, my ajax function get the datas and i set these datas on my datatables.

Here is my js:

```
$('#submit_search_type_client').on('click', function(e){
    var idType = $('#lst_type').val();
    var idclient = $('#frmTab_Client_type').val();
    var data = "idType=" + idType + "&idClient=" + idclient;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: root_url + "client/getTypes",
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success){
                var source = data.myreturn;
                $('#mydatatables').dataTable( {
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "pageLength": 5,
                    language: {
                        url: 'views/js/plugins/datatables/french.json'
                    },
                    "ajax": source
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(data){

        }
    }); // End ajax
});
```

My PHP Function that return my datas:

```
if($myresult= $this->db->query($requete))
{
    $myresult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $line = $myresult->fetchAll();
}

$tab['data'] = json_encode($line);

echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true', 'myreturn'=>$tab));
```

If i let PDO::FETCH_NUM, my jsonlooks like this:

```
{"success":"true","myreturn":{"data":"[[\"6017\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"01\\\/09\\\/2017 08:00\"],[\"6018\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"01\\\/09\\\/2017 09:00\"],[\"6019\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"01\\\/09\\\/2017 10:00\"],[\"6020\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"01\\\/09\\\/2017 11:00\"],[\"6021\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"01\\\/09\\\/2017 12:00\"],[\"6052\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"05\\\/09\\\/2017 19:00\"],[\"6156\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"21\\\/09\\\/2017 15:00\"],[\"6163\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"22\\\/09\\\/2017 10:00\"],[\"6166\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"22\\\/09\\\/2017 13:00\"],[\"6167\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"22\\\/09\\\/2017 14:00\"],[\"6170\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"22\\\/09\\\/2017 17:00\"],[\"6172\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"22\\\/09\\\/2017 19:00\"],[\"6204\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"28\\\/09\\\/2017 15:00\"],[\"6223\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"02\\\/10\\\/2017 10:00\"],[\"6224\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"02\\\/10\\\/2017 11:00\"],[\"6225\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"02\\\/10\\\/2017 12:00\"],[\"6244\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"03\\\/10\\\/2017 19:00\"],[\"6263\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"06\\\/10\\\/2017 14:00\"],[\"6264\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"06\\\/10\\\/2017 15:00\"],[\"6265\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"06\\\/10\\\/2017 16:00\"],[\"6266\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"06\\\/10\\\/2017 17:00\"],[\"6277\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"09\\\/10\\\/2017 16:00\"],[\"6278\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"09\\\/10\\\/2017 17:00\"],[\"6288\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"10\\\/10\\\/2017 15:00\"],[\"6290\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"10\\\/10\\\/2017 17:00\"]]"}}
```

I have no error from Datatables but no data in my datatables.

If in PHP i replace

```
$tab['data'] = json_encode($ine);

by

$tab['data'] = $line;
```

I receive THIS: "DataTables warning: table id=table_availabilities - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"

If in my PDO SELECT i replace PDO::FETCH_NUM by PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

I receive this: "DataTables warning: table id=table_availabilities - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"

I tried another thing, in my ajax, i set the source a textfile like that:

> {
>     "data": [
>       [
>         "TOTO",
>         "hihihi"
>       ],
>       [
>         "TOTO",
>         "hihihi"
>       ],
>       [
>         "TOTO",
>         "hihihi"
>       ],
>       [
>         "TOTO",
>         "hihihi"
>       ],
>       [
>         "TOTO",
>         "hihihi"
>       ],
>       [
>         "TOTO",
>         "hihihi"
>       ],
>            [
>              "TOTO",
>              "hihihi"
>            ]
>     ]
>    }

And it works, so i compare my json return with this text file and i see that i have :

```
{"data":"[[\"6017\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"01\\\/09\\\/2017 08:00\"],[\"6018\",\"Client Type TOTO\",\"01\\\/09\\\/2017 09:00\"], ...
```

the text file:

```
  {
  "data": [
    [
      "TOTO",
      "hihihi"
    ],
    [
      "TOTO",
      "hihihi"
    ], ...
```

The difference is that juste after "data": i have this: " it seems it's a string, ow can i correct this please?

Thanks

Comment: So, `ajax` option should contain URL to data. `data.myreturn` is not a valid URL.

Comment: if i write console.log(data.myreturn) i have a json string that i tested in https://jsonlint.com/ it's good.

Comment: Understand the difference between __url to script__ and __json string with data__.

Comment: you're right, i don't understand the difference. i just read the doc but still don't understand... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the manual, where you will see, that `ajax` options requires a **link** to script which gives back some data.

In your case `data.myreturn` is not a **link** to script, it is a **string with data**. Also I don't understand why you do ajax-request and then in a callback another ajax request from `datatables` is fired. I suppose this comes from misunderstanding of `ajax` property.

So, what you need to change:

```
$('#submit_search_type_client').on('click', function(e){
    var idType = $('#lst_type').val();
    var idclient = $('#frmTab_Client_type').val();
    var data = "idType=" + idType + "&idClient=" + idclient;
    // Full url
    var url = root_url + "client/getTypes?" + data;

    $('#mydatatables').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "pageLength": 5,
        language: {
            url: 'views/js/plugins/datatables/french.json'
        },
        // Full url is passed to ajax. URL, not data
        // Ajax request to this `url` should return data
        "ajax": url
    } );
});
```

In your php you can do this:

```
$line = [];
if($myresult= $this->db->query($requete))
{
    $myresult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $line = $myresult->fetchAll();
}
// Return data key only
echo json_encode(array('data' => $line));
```

**Final warnings**. By default, method of passing data to `ajax` option value is GET. So, I created `url` as url with GET-parameters.

You can change method to `POST` as said in [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax), but then you have to do some magic with passing data as parameters in post-request. But everything is described in docs.

Comment: thanks a lot for the time you spent to this answer. I'll test what you said later and i come back here to tell if it's ok.

Comment: hi, i readapt your code to mine and it works fine. Thank you however, when data is empty i receive a Warning from datatable: DataTables warning: table id=mydatatable - true How can i avoid it please?

Comment: OK i used to returned json_encode(array('error'=>'true', 'message'=>'My message')), when i have nothing to return, but i changed it to json_encode(array('data'=>'')) and i don't receive message from Datatable.

Comment: BUT (sorry), i have a question, i send a DT_RowId because i would like to create a link in the first column and use this ID. Any idea about how to do that?